# Is it possible to enforce MFA on AWS for all users?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Ia m trying to enforce all users to setup MFA login when they sign up. Is this something that is possible in AWS and how or where are the instructions to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of. You can essentially block non-admin users from making API calls without using MFA. There's a section about setting this up in this [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-delegate-management-of-multi-factor-authentication-to-aws-iam-users/). The blog post describes how to give someone access to setup MFA, and require MFA for every other interaction with the AWS API. I think this will require MFA to be used with calls from the SDK and CLI as well, so it might not be exactly what you want.

Also, I say this is only for non-admin users, because admin users would have the ability to go in and disable the MFA restriction on their account.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to do because the MFA device needs to be setup and once you do that, you need to enter information from the device.  Usually you have to enter two tokens in sequence to "synchronize" the device.

So you can't setup a virtual MFA for a user without the user.  However, if you had a hardware MFA device (see https://aws.amazon.com/iam/details/mfa/) then you could setup the user and the device and then give the user the device.

It's not perfect by any means.

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question? I'm not sure what point you're trying to make.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can definitely be done! Of course, admin and root users are able to disable the policy, but if you so desire, you can also limit who can update or disable the policy. When the enforcement policy is in effect, when the user logs in the only thing they have access to do is to enable the MFA for their IAM user. Once they then re-login with MFA enabled, they have the access they've been issued with the IAM policies/group memberships, etc.

It is not possible to enforce MFA only in the AWS web console, because the web console is essentially a front-end to the APIs which the AWS CLI tool also accesses. Starting and managing MFA (and role) sessions on the command line is a rather convoluted process, so you may be interested in a utility whose 2.0 version I just released. It makes it very easy to start and manage MFA and role sessions. I have also included an example enforcement policy that has been carefully built to work with the utility. A companion script is also provided to make it easy to enable/assign an MFA device from the command line (e.g. for the users who don't have web console access).

You can find the utility, more information about it, and the example policies in my GitHub at https://github.com/vwal/awscli-mfa